# Exception in converting Integer wrapper class to primitive long data type

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am writing a simple program related to the grid problem using Dynamic programming where I have used HashMap. I used integer as the return type and it worked just fine but for smaller values, when the values of rows of columns is big enough for the answer to be many digits long then the answer isn't returned properly.

I then switched int with long but I am getting the exception error. I have tried various ways to sort this out but it's still not getting passed. I was easily able to convert the Integer object to int value, but here I can't do it via any method.

Are there any alternative ways to sort this out?

```
import java.util.*;


public class Grid{

public static long grid_problem(int m, int n, HashMap h)
{   

// Convert the integers to string so as to create a unique key for every combination

String s1 = Integer.toString(m);
String s2 = Integer.toString(n);
String s=s1 + ',' + s2;
if(n==0||m==0)
{
    return 0; // Base Case
}
else if(n==1&&m==1)
{
    return 1; // Base Case
}
else if(h.containsKey(s)) // If the value is already stored
{
     
    Integer i = (Integer) h.get(s); // This step works fine 
    long l = i.longValue();         // I can't find any way to cast Integer to Long or     
    return l;                          int to long.
}
else
{
        long nth=grid_problem(m-1,n,h) + grid_problem(m,n-1,h); 
    h.put(s,nth);
    return nth; // return both halves of the binary tree
}
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
 HashMap<String, Integer> h = new HashMap<>();
 System.out.println(grid_problem(11,8,h));
}
}
```

Comment: [I then switched int with long but I am getting the exception error.](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you do `int + int` which can be `long`. You should keep in the `Map` `long` value insted of `int`.

```java
public static long gridProblem(int m, int n, Map<String, Long> map) {
    if (n == 0 || m == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1 && m == 1) return 1;

    String s = m + "," + n;

    if (map.containsKey(s)) return map.get(s);

    long nth = gridProblem(m - 1, n, map) + gridProblem(m, n - 1, map);
    map.put(s, nth);
    return nth;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Map<String, Long> h = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println(gridProblem(11, 8, h));
}
```

***P.S.** I know that using recursion is quite intuitive and simple, but only for test tasks. For big input, you can get `StackOverflowError`. It's better to use iterations instead. Check this out!*

```java
public static long gridProblem(int rows, int cols) {
    int[][] b = new int[rows][cols];
    long sum = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            if (row == 0 || col == 0) b[row][col] = 0;
            else if (row == 1 && col == 1) b[row][col] = 1;
            else b[row][col] = b[row][col - 1] + b[row - 1][col];

            sum += b[row][col];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Also, I was getting the stack overflow error earlier when I was dynamically allocating the HashMap at the start of the function. It disappeared when I removed that allocation, but I'll keep the tip in mind. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To convert **Integer** to **long** use the **longValue()** method available in the Integer class.
Which returns the value of the Integer as a long after a widening primitive conversion.

Example:

```
 Integer intVal = 10;

 long longVal = intVal.longValue();
```

Comment: I have used longValue() itself in my code, it doesn't work.